# How can i get the system type of a value i get from a form/string?

Tags: c#, mysql, gettype

i have never tried something like this so i need your help.

i have the following code:

```
    public int AddChannel(NameValueCollection FormValues)
    {
        string Keys = string.Join(",",FormValues.AllKeys);
        string Values = string.Join(",", FormValues.AllKeys.Select(key => String.Format("\"{0}\"", HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(FormValues[key]))));

        return InsertQuery("INSERT INTO channels (" + Keys + ") VALUES (" + Values + ");");
    }
```

while processing, some fields are supposed to be integers otherwise, the mysql query fails.
how can i check and convert KeyValue into the correct type?

Comment: I'm curious - why *html* encode the values? xss prevention is often applied outbound (not inbound) - and you are surely at much bigger risk here from SQL injection (I don't use mysql, but does it not allow parameters?)

Comment: actually i tried to SQL inject a simple ' just to see if it fails.
it does not appear to affect the query, the result is encoded allready.

Comment: since you are using `"` as your string delimiter, I would *expect* `'` to work OK. Now try a `"`... does that work OK?

Comment: `VALUES ("&quot;","&quot;","","","","","","","","","","","","","");`

Comment: meh - it is working but for the odd reason that you are using html encode for data, which is unusual. I *suspect* there will also be ways around that.... html encode is not normal here (except maybe if you are storing parallel raw/encoded versions so that you don't have to encode to display)

Comment: the input is mainly html & text. there is one field that containts an integer, which i would like to join to the form post.
at max, ill remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, none. The data coming in from a http post is text. You *could* try and infer that `123` is *probably* a number, but that isn't safe, as `"123"` is a perfectly valid string. Personally, I'd hope that the code knows the schema ahead of time, or can *access* the schema. And from the schema, apply the correct conversions (and then add the values via *parameters* of the appropriate types).

Comment: could you give an example for that?

Comment: about the schema and conversions.

Comment: @Dementic is the schema for `channels` known in advance? or does it change?

Comment: it does not change. and i can get a DataTable containing the schema if needed.

Comment: if it doesn't change, then your code *knows* the types - can't you just switch on the various keys to translate appropriately? or define a class and use the property-type (look up by name)...?